# How to get string between the last occurrence of a dot(.) and the end of the string and concat it with another string in C?

Tags: c, string, parsing

I have a filename that I need to parse to get the file type (.txt, .pdf, .jpg, etc.). I used `strrchr` to get the last occurrence of '.' from the filename. 
I have a `char *outputfilename = "output";` that I need to concatenate with the filetype to basically get "output.pdf" or "output.jpg" depending on the filename I've received.
Any leads?

Comment: What have you tried? `strrchr` is correct and will return a pointer to the final `'.'`. If you then validate the length of `p + 1` (to make sure it is reasonable for an extension) and validate that `p != string` (e.g. for `.bashrc`, etc.. *not a dot file*), you can then use `p + 1` to concatenate with your existing filename.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - I tried using strcat on outputfilename and p but that's wrong I guess. I'm still not clear on my pointers. Anyway, I didn't get what you meant by "If you then validate the length of p + 1 (to make sure it is reasonable for an extension) and validate that p != string"

Comment: You need to ensure that `outputfilename` is (pointing at) writable storage.  When you have `char *outputfilename = "output";`, it is pointing at a fixed amount of non-writable storage — not sufficient to store the suffix too.  So, you need `char outputfilename[80] = "output";` and then you can use `strcat(outputfilename, strrchr(inputfilename, '.'))` if you're confident that there is at least one dot in the file name.  If you're not sure, you'll find the dot separately from the call to `strcat()`.   I tend to assume anything that can go wrong will, so I'd split the 'find dot' operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `snprintf` (or `asprintf` if available), something like this:

```
FILE* open_with_extension(const char* base, const char* name) {
  const char* dotp = strrchr(name, '.');
  if (dotp) {
    char filename[MAX_PATH];
    int sz = snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "%s%s", base, dotp);
    if (sz < sizeof filename) {
      return fopen(filename, "wb");
    }
    else {
      /* Name + extension too long */
      return NULL;
    }
  }
  else {
    /* No extension, some kind of error? */
    return NULL;
  }
}
```

`snprintf` is both safer and easier than `strcat`, and is a lot more flexible. And it probably is not much slower, certainly not enough to notice in an applications such as this one.

If you do more than a few successive `strcat` calls to build up a string in quadratic time, you might even find that `snprintf` turns out to be faster. Regardless, it's almost always more readable.